# Emails are failing when I use FormatDate in Sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid-templates

I am trying to get the format as "MMMM DD, YYYY" but when I use

{{ FormatDate this.value "MMMM DD,YYYY" }}

it works on preview but the Emails were undelivered.

When I use,

{{this.value}}

same template works!! need guidance on this!!